# How to make Clangd in VSCode only index the currently open file and standard header files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

I am an algorithmic competition participant, and I have a VSCode workspace where I have organized my code from various online judging systems into folders. The directory tree looks roughly like this:

```
OI (Workspace Root)
- Codeforces
- - CF001A.cpp
- - CF002B.cpp
- ATCoder
- - abc001_a.cpp
- - abc002_b.cpp
- luogu
- - P1001.cpp
- - P1002.cpp
```

Clearly, my problem files are independent of each other, and I don't need or want to include the contents of other files in one file. I only need to include system header files like `iostream` and `vector`.

However, when my problem repository folder reaches a certain size, I noticed that the response time of `clangd` becomes significantly slower. Below is a part of the `clangd` log where it can be observed that many operations take several thousand milliseconds.

```
I[10:43:16.044] Indexing c++2b standard library in the context of d:/Coding/OI/atcoder/abc261_g.cpp
I[10:43:16.195] Built preamble of size 7253168 for file d:/Coding/OI/atcoder/abc261_g.cpp version 1 in 0.97 seconds
......
I[10:43:18.601] Indexed c++2b standard library: 14142 symbols, 958 filtered
I[10:43:19.203] --> textDocument/publishDiagnostics
I[10:43:19.205] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(1) 3818 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
[Error - 10:43:19] Request textDocument/documentLink failed.
[object Object]
I[10:43:19.205] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(2) 3809 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
I[10:43:19.206] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(3) 3801 ms, error: Task was cancelled.
[Error - 10:43:19] Request textDocument/inlayHint failed.
[object Object]
[Error - 10:43:19] Request textDocument/inlayHint failed.
[object Object]
I[10:43:19.207] --> reply:textDocument/semanticTokens/full(5) 3382 ms
I[10:43:19.208] --> reply:textDocument/documentLink(6) 3210 ms
I[10:43:19.209] --> reply:textDocument/documentSymbol(7) 2103 ms
I[10:43:19.210] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(8) 1800 ms
I[10:43:19.210] --> reply:textDocument/inlayHint(9) 1800 ms
I[10:43:19.211] --> reply:textDocument/codeAction(11) 793 ms
```

However, when I created a workspace with only one file, the performance of `clangd` returned to normal.

```
Playground (Workspace Root)
- test1.cpp
```

I suspect that Clangd scans the entire folder (or even the workspace) of code every time it performs autocompletion (even though I haven't included them). How can I change this behavior?

I have tried setting `clangd` parameters such as `-j=8`, `--background-index=false`, `--pch-storage=memory`, and so on, but they were all ineffective.

**EDIT: I conformed that `clangd` will parse the dictionary the current opened file in.**

**EDIT: The problem only occurs in Windows.**

Comment: Do you have any kind of `compile_commands.json`? It would expect it to autoindex only if the file exists.

Comment: No, I use clangd.fallbackFlags instead. "-Wall -std=c++2b -Wextra -Wno-unused-variable"

Comment: Can't reproduce on Clangd 16. Created an empty directory, added two .cpp files. Not getting completions from one file in another, not getting `.cache` directory generated.

Comment: I'm using clangd 16. Just paste some code ~6kb into a .cpp file, and copy the file for ~100 times in the same folder, you'll notice the problem.

Comment: Can you upload the code you're testing it on to pastebin?

Comment: Just clone it, open the OI folder with VSCode, open a .cpp in ATCoder/
https://github.com/d0j1a1701/OI_database/tree/decced8e2076f656cae648696e9a6c8640b06464

Comment: No issues on my side, Clangd responds immediately. Can you show your settings in `settings.json` related to Clangd? Also search the directory for `.cache` and `compile_commands.json`, in case you got them from somewhere. Or perhaps you have other extensions that affect this?

Comment: "clangd.arguments": [
        "--background-index",
        "--all-scopes-completion",
        "--header-insertion=iwyu",
        "--pch-storage=disk",
        "--cross-file-rename",
        "--clang-tidy",
        "--pretty"
    ]，no .cache or compile_commands.json found

Comment: I'm using mingw64 with LLVM from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: What happens if you remove all those arguments? Especially `--background-index`. Also I was testing on Linux, maybe there's some difference here.

Comment: Nothing Happen. Maybe I can try to test with VSCode in WSL2.

Comment: Make sure you clone the specialized commit. I classified my codebase in the latest commit in order to temporarily resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, I tested on commit `decced8`.

Comment: Did you restart VSC after removing `--background-index`?

Comment: OK. I conformed that the problem only occurs in Windows. HolyBlackCat, have you got a Windows VM?